# How do I paint a ball on a mouseclick in C# using winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the code below at the moment. When the form loads, a ball is created and moves with the mouse, but now I want to create a Ball (FilledEllipse) on a mouseclick and then have it appear where I clicked. The overall goal is to then have it start moving and bounce around the screen so I can create multiple ones, but first things first. I am using a Ball class I created that just sets the radius of the ball.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint; 
        this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
        this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point local = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, local.X , local.Y , 20, 20);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Ball myBall = new Ball(random.Next(1, 5));
    }      

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're looking at making a game in C# I recommend taking a look at XNA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `List<Ball>` and add the ball created on mouseclick to this list.

In the OnPaint, paint every ball in the list.

In the OnClick also call Refresh, to refresh the list.

I added stuff to your code:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Create list 
    List<Ball> _balls = new List<Ball>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint; 
        this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
        this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseClick;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point local = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, local.X , local.Y , 20, 20);

        // Paint each stored ball
        foreach(var ball in _balls) {
           // paint ball
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Ball myBall = new Ball(random.Next(1, 5));

        // Store ball, and refresh screen
        _balls.Add(myBall);
        Invalidate()
    }      

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

To move the ball, in the OnPaint you calculate the new position (of each ball) before you paint it.

Take in account the time since the last OnPaint to create a flexible movement.

Can I also suggest to take a look at WPF. This library is a replacement for Windows Forms and contains a lot of solutions for painting and animations.